# Sending Multipart Form Data in Android

Tags: java, android, http, multipartform-data

I have used the below code (taken from SO) to post some data to a PHP script:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Web.API_PREFIX_GENERAL + "ajax/process.AL.php");

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("mail", new StringBody("abcd@abcd.com"));
reqEntity.addPart("remote", new StringBody("1"));
reqEntity.addPart("altitle", new StringBody("GHI"));
reqEntity.addPart("aldesc", new StringBody("JKL"));
reqEntity.addPart("t", new StringBody("N"));
reqEntity.addPart("lat", new StringBody(lati));
reqEntity.addPart("long", new StringBody(longi));
reqEntity.addPart("p", new StringBody("all"));

httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

**...And this does not produce anything. No error, but nothing gets posted either.**

However, if I use something like below and have no parts added to `reqEntity`,

```
String url = Web.API_PREFIX_GENERAL + "ajax/process.AL.php?mail=abcd@abcd.com&remote=1&altitle=GHI" +
                    "&aldesc=JKL&t=N&lat=" + lati + "&long=" + longi + "&p=all";

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

**...this works**

I have all the required Apache libraries set up also. So any idea why this is?

I need to use `MultipartEntity` because I'll also have to post an image later.

Thanks.

Comment: **And this does not work.** What does this mean? Are you getting any error?

Comment: put your code in a try-catch block and check your stacktrace

Comment: @javapirate Actually, it works. But nothing happens. No error, no posted stuff either.

Comment: @Roshnal what if `process.AL.php` uses $_GET instead of $_POST

Comment: @SherifelKhatib No, it should be working correctly as the iPhone app (of the same project, but done by another. Not me) works using this link. And also the Windows 8 app.

Comment: @Roshnal According to `what works` and `what does not work` in your question, it is a possibility that the php script is reading GET parameters and not POST ones.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib I will try to contact our PHP guy and ask him. I did not think that it was a server-side error...

Comment: You should get your PHP guy to send down 405s if you send the wrong method up. Something as simple as this will save you hours and hours of dev time. You can then just check the status code, which'll tell you exactly what's going on. I guess you've tried this already.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem isn't in the client side but in the server side.
In the second example you are sending an HTTP POST but you are sending parameters like a GET.

Usually a Multipart request is used when you send data file (i.e. upload a file), but it seems to me in your code you aren't sending any data file, so you shouldn't use a multipart request.

Comment: Yeah, that may be the case. I have to check with the server-side programming guys and then I'll post back here.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and monitor the http request using a http proxy tool.
It works. Maybe some error occur in your php code.

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        testUpload();
        return null;
    }

}

public void testUpload() {  
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.google.com/" + "ajax/process.AL.php");

    try {
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("mail", new StringBody("abcd@abcd.com"));
        reqEntity.addPart("remote", new StringBody("1"));
        reqEntity.addPart("altitle", new StringBody("GHI"));
        reqEntity.addPart("aldesc", new StringBody("JKL"));
        reqEntity.addPart("t", new StringBody("N"));
        reqEntity.addPart("p", new StringBody("all"));

        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with the integer to string conversion. Try this:

```
reqEntity.addPart("lat", new StringBody(Integer.toString(lati)));
reqEntity.addPart("long", new StringBody(Integer.toString(longi)));
```

You can use `lati + ""` instead of `Integer.toString(lati)`.